# Human-readable self-describing entities and localization

Tags: .net, domain-driven-design

I'm building a simple CRUD system that manages customer accounts for a business. Nothing special :)

The application is in two parts: a culture-agnostic model layer which is where the EF entity classes are kept. The front-end is an ASP.NET MVC project that performs all of the localization tasks.

I have a series of similar EF entities that represent add-on services for each account, they all implement the interface `IAccountService`, for example:

```
public interface IAccountService {

    String DisplayName { get; set; }
    String Overview    { get; set; }
}

public partial class IntenseAuditService : IAccountService {

    // Example database columns:
    public DateTime DateTimeOfAudit { get; set; }
    public Boolean ThreatenToReportThemToTheIrs { get; set; }
    public Int32 Iterations { get; set; }

    public String DisplayName { get { return "Intense audit"; } }

    public String Overview {
        get {
            String ret = "Audit on ";
            ret += this.DateTimeOfAudit.ToString();
            if( ThreatenToReportThemToTheIrs ) {
                ret += ", and report them to the feds"
            }
            if( Iterations == 1 ) ret += " and 1 iteration";
            else if( Iterations > 1 ) ret += " and " + Iterations + " iterations.";
            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

The main problem is that the text isn't localized, nor can it be easily localized: simply passing in a format-string doesn't solve the problem of pluralisation of English grammar, and doesn't necessary work with other languages.

A possible solution is to remove the Overview string generation logic from the model library and moving it to the consumer application project (where localisation is done anyway), however the model library is also responsible for generating other entities that might have Overview messages contained within them, for example, part of the system automatically generates entries in a `CalendarItem` table that has a `Description` column populated with the Overview from an `IAccountService`. I don't know how to untie this knot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're headed in the right direction - handling localization in the ASP.NET MVC presentation layer. One way to implement would be to effectively maintain a class hierarchy in the presentation layer which resolves localization for corresponding domain entities. The domain model would not even expose such properties as `DisplayName` and `Overview` - those would be in entirely in the presentation layer.

To localize something like `Overview` for `IntenseAuditService` you can have a `IntenseAuditServiceViewModel` where the overview property retrieves a localized format string where you provide the 'variables' such as the number of iterations, the audit date, etc. You can handle inflections explicitly by having both a plural and singular string formats. So in this case, you could have 4 localized resources called IntenseAuditServiceOverview_DoReport_Plural, IntenseAuditServiceOverview_DoReport_Singular, IntenseAuditServiceOverview_NoReport_Plural, IntenseAuditServiceOverview_NoReport_Singular with the first format string in en-US being something like

> Audit on {0:yyyyMMdd},and report them to the feds and {1:#,0}
>   iterations.

Depending on your localization needs, you may be able to factor this differently. Another way, is to just have a localized version of each sub-string. You may also need further customization for each language.

Comment: Thanks. My solution was to return a `Dictionary<String,Object>` and get the client format that with known strings, using named string placeholders.